# UIStoryboard name and bundle

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this line of code:

```
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *) bundle (NSBundle *)];
```

and a storyboard file. Where do I actually insert the name of the controller, and where do I find the bundle?

It is a stupid question, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Small code typo. Add a colon after `bundle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything is really straightforward!

This is the code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = 
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                          bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Where is **@"Main Storyboard"** is the name of your **.storyboard** file. Bundle is just the bundle that contains your **.storyboard** file, usually is the main bundle of your app.

If you want to get access to some of the UIViewControllers, for example, with the purpose of pushing it to the stack of your UINavigationController, then you must do this:

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = 
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifier"];
```

You can set Identifier to your UIViewController in the Xcode's Identity Inspector!

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 9):

The `name`parameter is **the name of your `.storyboard` file** (without the extension).

The `bundle` is usually the main bundle of your application. In general, you pass `nil` so that the runtime will search your storyboard file in the main bundle by default (same as if you pass `[NSBundle mainBundle]`). And in practice you generally only have one bundle in iOS applications, which is the main bundle representing your IPA bundle, so `nil` is the common value for this parameter)

For example, if you have a storyboard named `MyStory.storyboard` your would write:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStory" bundle:nil];
```

---

Actually all of this is explained [in the Apple documentation for this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:).

> ### storyboardWithName:bundle:
>
> Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard resource file.
>
> `+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `name`: **The name of the storyboard resource file without the filename extension**. This method raises an exception if this parameter is nil.
> - `storyboardBundleOrNil`: The bundle containing the storyboard file and its related resources. If you specify nil, this method looks in the main bundle of the current application.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Maybe sharing how this instantiates a new UIStoryboard reference from the specific name.  Also consider passing in `[NSBundle mainBundle]` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 Version:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

In this example, I used the default "Main" storyboard file as the reference.